# How to join to column after imputation

Tags: r, imputation

I ran multiple imputation to impute missing data for 2 variables of a data frame, then I got a new data frame (with 2 columns for 2 imputed variables).

Now, I want to replace the 2 columns in the original data frame with the two newly imputed columns from my new dataframe.
What should I do?

[Original data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHrwa.png)
[new data frame for imputed variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuKQX.png)

This is the code I used. Only 2 columns in this data frame are missing data, so I only imputed those two. Is that ok? Can you please suggest me a better way?

```
library("mice")
imi<-mice(subset(data,select=c('ABV','EBC')),m=5,maxit=10)
```

Data

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(58L, 188L, 40L, 155L, 32L, 
88L, 92L, 55L, 135L, 31L, 139L, 26L, 126L, 10L, 166L, 104L, 75L, 
180L, 35L, 175L, 77L, 99L, 4L, 71L, 141L, 176L, 53L, 39L, 172L, 
196L, 123L, 107L, 16L, 96L, 82L, 185L, 30L, 15L, 94L, 129L, 187L, 
151L, 33L, 23L, 28L, 44L, 157L, 69L, 132L, 83L, 131L, 11L, 182L, 
181L, 54L, 115L, 116L, 183L, 150L, 195L, 45L, 144L, 1L, 110L, 
17L, 114L, 9L, 117L, 112L, 70L, 34L, 169L, 27L, 66L, 3L, 73L, 
133L, 91L, 154L, 130L, 160L, 105L, 90L, 165L, 67L, 100L, 162L, 
98L, 29L, 68L, 189L, 192L, 102L, 190L, 134L, 136L, 52L, 12L, 
81L, 59L, 63L, 122L, 93L, 109L, 178L, 138L, 5L, 43L, 140L, 95L, 
2L, 174L, 76L, 51L, 156L, 60L, 149L, 128L, 177L, 142L, 103L, 
7L, 8L, 14L, 164L, 74L, 145L, 148L, 113L, 86L, 108L, 48L, 163L, 
6L, 186L, 89L, 36L, 191L, 125L, 120L, 62L, 65L, 124L, 168L, 147L, 
79L, 173L, 84L, 193L, 25L, 146L, 121L, 127L, 153L, 13L, 106L, 
119L, 161L, 49L, 97L, 101L, 61L, 137L, 24L, 85L, 194L, 78L, 41L, 
170L, 47L, 118L, 184L, 179L, 72L, 42L, 111L, 87L, 57L, 38L, 37L, 
171L, 22L, 50L, 80L, 159L, 18L, 152L, 64L, 56L, 158L, 167L, 46L, 
19L, 21L, 20L, 143L), .Label = c("#Mashtag 2013", "#Mashtag 2014", 
"#Mashtag 2015", "10 Heads High", "5am Saint", "77 Lager", "AB:02", 
"AB:03", "AB:04", "AB:06", "AB:08", "AB:10", "AB:11", "AB:13", 
"AB:15", "AB:17", "AB:18", "AB:20", "Ace Of Chinook", "Ace Of Citra", 
"Ace Of Equinox", "Ace Of Simcoe", "Albino Squid Assasin", "Alice Porter", 
"All Day Long - Prototype Challenge", "Alpha Dog", "Alpha Pop", 
"Amarillo - IPA Is Dead", "American Ale", "Anarchist Alchemist", 
"Arcade Nation", "Avery Brown Dredge", "Baby Dogma", "Baby Saison - B-Sides", 
"Bad Pixie", "Barley Wine - Russian Doll", "Barrel Aged Albino Squid Assassin", 
"Barrel Aged Hinterland", "Berliner Weisse With Raspberries And Rhubarb - B-Sides", 
"Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides", "Bitch Please (w/ 3 Floyds)", 
"Black Dog", "Black Eye Joe (w/ Stone Brewing Co)", "Black Eyed King Imp", 
"Black Eyed King Imp - Vietnamese Coffee Edition", "Black Hammer", 
"Black Jacques", "Black Tokyo Horizon (w/NÃ¸gne Ã\230 & Mikkeller)", 
"Blitz Berliner Weisse", "Blitz Series", "Born To Die", "Bounty Hunter - Shareholder Brew", 
"Bourbon Baby", "Bracken's Porter", "Bramling X", "Brewdog Vs Beavertown", 
"Brixton Porter", "Buzz", "Candy Kaiser", "Cap Dog (w/ Cap Brewery)", 
"Catherine's Pony (w/ Beavertown)", "Challenger", "Chaos Theory", 
"Chili Hammer", "Chinook - IPA Is Dead", "Citra", "Clown King", 
"Cocoa Psycho", "Coffee Imperial Stout", "Comet", "Dana - IPA Is Dead", 
"Dead Metaphor", "Dead Pony Club", "Deaf Mermaid - B-Sides", 
"Devine Rebel (w/ Mikkeller)", "Dog A", "Dog B", "Dog C", "Dog D", 
"Dog E", "Dog Fight (w/ Flying Dog)", "Dog Wired (w/8 Wired)", 
"Dogma", "Doodlebug", "Double IPA - Russian Doll", "Edge", "El Dorado - IPA Is Dead", 
"Electric India", "Ella - IPA Is Dead", "Elvis Juice V2.0 - Prototype Challenge", 
"Everday Anarchy", "Fake Lager", "Galaxy", "Goldings - IPA Is Dead", 
"Growler", "Hardcore IPA", "Hardkogt IPA", "HBC 366 - IPA Is Dead", 
"HBC 369", "Hello My Name Is Beastie", "Hello My Name Is Holy Moose", 
"Hello My Name Is Ingrid", "Hello My Name Is Little Ingrid", 
"Hello My Name Is Mette-Marit", "Hello My Name Is PaÌ\210ivi", 
"Hello My Name is Sonja (w/ Evil Twin)", "Hello My Name is Vladimir", 
"Hello My Name Is ZeÌ\201 (w/ 2CabecÌ§as)", "Hinterland", "Hobo Pop", 
"Hop Fiction - Prototype Challenge", "Hopped-Up Brown Ale - Prototype Challenge", 
"Hoppy Christmas", "Hops Kill Nazis", "Hunter Foundation Pale Ale", 
"Hype", "India Session Lager - Prototype Challenge", "International Arms Race (w/ Flying Dog)", 
"Interstellar", "Jack Hammer", "Jasmine IPA", "Jet Black Heart", 
"Kohatu - IPA Is Dead", "Konnichiwa Kitsune", "Libertine Black Ale", 
"Libertine Porter", "Lichtenstein Pale Ale", "Lizard Bride - Prototype Challenge", 
"Lost Dog (w/Lost Abbey)", "Lumberjack Stout", "Magic Stone Dog (w/Magic Rock & Stone Brewing Co.)", 
"Mandarina Bavaria - IPA Is Dead", "Mango Gose - B-Sides", "Melon And Cucumber IPA - B-Sides", 
"Misspent Youth", "Morag's Mojito - B-Sides", "Moshi Moshi 15", 
"Motueka", "Movember", "Mr.Miyagi's Wasabi Stout", "Nanny State", 
"Nelson Sauvin", "Neon Overlord", "Never Mind The Anabolics", 
"No Label", "Nuns With Guns", "Old World India Pale Ale", "Old World Russian Imperial Stout", 
"Orange Blossom - B-Sides", "Pale - Russian Doll", "Paradox Islay", 
"Paradox Islay 2.0", "Paradox Jura", "Peroxide Punk", "Pilsen Lager", 
"Pioneer - IPA Is Dead", "Prototype 27", "Prototype Helles", 
"Prototype Pils 2.0", "Pumpkin King", "Punk IPA 2007 - 2010", 
"Punk IPA 2010 - Current", "Restorative Beverage For Invalids And Convalescents", 
"Rhubarb Saison - B-Sides", "Riptide", "Russian Doll â\200“ India Pale Ale", 
"Rye Hammer", "San Diego Scotch Ale (w/Ballast Point)", "Santa Paws", 
"Shareholder Black IPA 2011", "Ship Wreck", "Shipwrecker Circus (w/ Oskar Blues)", 
"Simcoe", "Sink The Bismarck!", "Skull Candy", "Sorachi Ace", 
"Sorachi Bitter - B-Sides", "Spiced Cherry Sour - B-Sides", "Stereo Wolf Stout - Prototype Challenge", 
"Storm", "Sub Hop", "Sunk Punk", "Sunmaid Stout", "Sunshine On Rye - B-Sides", 
"The Physics", "This. Is. Lager", "TM10", "Trashy Blonde", "Truffle and Chocolate Stout - B-Sides", 
"U-Boat (w/ Victory Brewing)", "Vagabond Pale ALe - Prototype Challenge", 
"Vagabond Pilsner", "Vic Secret", "Waimea - IPA Is Dead", "Whisky Sour - B-Sides", 
"Zephyr"), class = "factor"), ABV = c(4.5, 4.1, 4.2, 6.3, 7.2, 
NA, 4.7, 7.5, 7.3, 5.3, 4.5, 4.5, 6.1, 11.2, 6, 8.2, 12.5, 8, 
4.7, 3.5, 15, 6.7, 7.8, 6.7, 0.5, 7.5, 5.8, 3.6, 10.5, 12.5, 
7.2, 8.2, 10.7, 9.2, 7.1, 5, 16.5, 12.8, 6.7, 10, NA, 10, 4.5, 
7.4, 7.2, 9.5, 9.2, 9, 7.2, 7.5, NA, 10.43, 7.1, 8, 5, 5.4, 4.1, 
10.2, 4, 7, 12.7, 6.5, 7.5, 4.2, 11.8, 7.6, 15, 4.4, 6.3, 7.2, 
NA, 4.5, 4.5, 7.5, 10, 3.8, 6.4, NA, 4, 15.2, 5.4, 8.3, 6.5, 
8, 12, 8.2, 5.6, 7.2, 6.3, 10, 5.6, 4.5, 8.2, 8.4, 6, 6.7, 6.5, 
11.5, 8.5, 5.2, 7.1, 4.7, 6.7, 9, 6.5, 6.7, 5, 5.8, 7.5, 4.5, 
9, 41, 15, 8.5, 7.2, 9, 3.8, 5.7, 6.3, 7.5, 4.4, 18, 10.5, 11.3, 
NA, 5.2, 4.5, 9.5, 7.2, 2.7, 6.4, 17.2, 8.5, 4.9, 4.7, 7.2, 10, 
4.5, 7.2, 7.2, 6.7, 7.2, 4.4, 9, 7.5, 16.1, 6.7, 2.5, 7.4, 2.8, 
4.2, 5.8, 5.2, 10, 12.8, 8.3, 6.5, 6, 3, 7.6, 5.5, 8.8, 5.2, 
5.2, 8, 6.7, 15, 11.5, 7.1, NA, 7.5, 7.2, 5.2, 6.8, 5.5, 5.2, 
6.7, 5, 9, 9.2, 13.8, 4.5, 3.2, 16.1, 4.7, 14.2, 13, 7.2, 9.2, 
4.9, 7.2, 7.2, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 7.6), IBU = c(60, 41.5, 8, 55, 
59, 38, 40, 75, 30, 60, 50, 42, 45, 150, 70, 70, 100, 60, 45, 
33, 90, 67, 70, 70, 55, 75, 35, 8, 85, 125, 70, 70, 100, 125, 
65, 47, 20.5, 50, 70, 35, 20, 55, 35, 65, 70, 85, 149, 65, 100, 
30, 30, 65, 68, 35, 50, 35, 65, 50, 35, 20, 85, 35, 50, 50, 80, 
70, 80, 35, 85, 70, 9, 35, 30, 70, 85, 35, 40, 45, 40, 20, 20, 
70, 60, 45, 85, 42, 40, 70, 55, 85, 30, 55, 42, 50, 50, 40, 35, 
80, 65, 45, 90, 45, 67, 85, 20, 67, 30, 40, 90, 38, 50, 1085, 
90, 85, 100, 80, 20, 35, 130, 75, 35, 70, 14, 50, 25, 65, 25, 
80, 70, 36, 50, 75, 100, 30, 37, 100, 80, 55, 50, 250, 67, 100, 
70, 70, 80, 85, 70, 35, 70, 30, 25, 40, 50, 55, 70, 70, 55, 60, 
8, 175, 35, 40, 45, 55, 85, 70, 90, 50, 80, 45, 0, 130, 55, 30, 
60, 40, 70, 50, 85, 65, 60, 40, 8, 100, 25, 20, 100, 250, 50, 
18, 250, 250, 40, 40, 40, 70), OG = c(1044, 1041.7, 1040, 1060, 
1069, 1045, 1046, 1068, 1079, 1052, 1047, 1046, 1067, 1098, 1058, 
1076, 1093, 1082, 1047, 1038, 1120, 1013, 1074, 1066, 1007, 1068, 
1049, 1040, 1102, 1087, 1067, 1076, 1105, 1085, 1065, 1048.5, 
1112, 1096, 1066, 1080, 1048, 1090, 1048, 1069, 1067, 1095, 1083, 
1080, 1064, 1080, 1043, 1095, 1056, 1077, 1049, 1050, 1042, 1026, 
1041, 1081, 1113.5, 1050, 1070, 1042, 1096, 1073, 1113, 1040, 
1063, 1067, 1032, 1048, 1045, 1068, 1098, 1040, 1057, 1081, 1039, 
1110, 1055, 1076, 1060, 1075, 1130, 1078, 1055, 1067, 1060, 1098, 
1058, 1046, 1078, 1080, 1050, 1063, 1068, 1096, 1078, 1049, 1067, 
1055, 1013, 1094, 1060, 1013, 1050, 1053, 1072, 1042.9, 1084, 
1085, 1120, 1072, 1064, 1083, 1039, 1053, 1060, 1068, 1045, 1150, 
1093, 1098, 1052, 1048, 1043, 1075, 1067, 1033, 1061, 1156, 1068, 
1047, 1043, 1064, 1097, 1045, 1068, 1065, 1064, 1064, 1045, 1090, 
1069, 1125, 1063, 1027, 1069, 1032.5, 1044, 1060, 1050, 1128, 
1108, 1076, 1059, 1056, 1007, 1072, 1053, 1084, 1048, 1053, 1074, 
1066, 1120, 1104, 1067, 1089, 1069, 1065, 1052, 1068, 1062, 1048, 
1066, 1053, 1094, 1069, 1088, 1045, 1007, 1015, 1008, 1025, 1015, 
1065, 1016, 1010, 1065, 1065, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1067), EBC = c(20, 
15, 8, 30, 10, 15, 12, 22, 120, 200, 140, 62, 219, 70, 25, NA, 
36, 12, 8, 50, 100, 19, 90, 30, 30, 30, 44, NA, 64, 40, 30, 16, 
300, 40, 13, 65, 20, 111, 30, 80, 14, 300, 40, 60, 30, 250, 19.5, 
97, 12, 46, 15, 23, 14, 15, 110, 11.5, 17, 197, 45, 12, 250, 
23, 40, 30, 115, 59, 400, 12, 24, 30, 2, 44, 25, 30, 130, 25, 
10, 15, 18, 158, 30, 30, 25, 240, 24, 90, 15, 30, 30, 30, 54, 
25, 70, 200, 8, 15, 250, 115, 31.2, 45, 15, 200, 19, 400, NA, 
19, 60, 177.3, 200, 18, 20, 40, 100, 15, 12, 180, 6, 25, 14, 
30, 30, 57, NA, 164, 10, 16, 10, 195, 30, 57, 20, 128, 15, 12, 
10, 12, 65, 20, 150, 15, 19, 12, 30, 190, 50, 400, 30, 10, 30, 
42, 19, 35, 17, 300, 79, 30, 50, 17, 9, 40, 25, 190, 35, 165, 
35, 30, 100, 38, 71, 15, 50, 14, 200, 86, 230, 13, 30, 200, 400, 
60, 25, 18, 8, 500, 25, 67, 300, 15, 78.8, 13, 17, 104, 18, 18, 
18, 20), PH = c(4.4, 4.4, 3.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 
4.2, 5.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 5.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 
4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 3.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.3, 4.4, 4.4, 
4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 
4.4, 4.5, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 5.2, 3.2, 5.2, 
4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 5.2, 4.4, 4, 4.4, 4.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 
4.4, 4.4, 3.5, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 
4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 5.2, 5.2, 4.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.2, 
4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.3, 3.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 
4.4, 4.4, 5.2, 5.2, 4.4, 5.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 5.2, 5.2, 
4.2, 4.5, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.2, 4.4, 
4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.3, 4.4, 4.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 
4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 3.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.5, 4.4, 5.2, 5.2, 
4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 5.2, 5.2, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 
4.3, 4.2, 4.4, 4.2, 3.2, 4.4, 4.2, 4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.2, 4.2, 4.4, 
4.4, 4.2, 4.2, 4.2, 4.4), AttenuationLevel = c(75, 76, 83, 80, 
67, 88.9, 78, 80.9, 74.7, 77, 74.5, 72.8, 70.1, 87, 79.3, 83, 
68, 86, 79, 68.4, 98, 79.7, 79.7, 77.3, 28.6, 82.1, 90, 83, 102, 
81.2, 82.1, 83, 76.2, 81.2, 85, 79.4, 100, 79.17, 77.3, 85, 89.6, 
84.4, 72.9, 82.6, 82.1, 76.8, 83, 76, 84, 70, 81.4, 83.2, 82.1, 
79.2, 79, 84, 76.2, 74.5, 75.6, 74, 76.8, 76, 81.4, 76.2, 79.2, 
79.5, 84.1, 79.5, 82.6, 82.1, 88, 72.9, 75.6, 82.1, 79.6, 70, 
87, 93.8, 76.9, 82, 74.6, 82.9, 83.3, 81.3, 102.3, 83.3, 78, 
82.1, 80, 70, 74, 73.9, 83.3, 81.3, 87, 84, 70.6, 79.2, 84.6, 
81.6, 80.6, 70, 79.7, 73.4, 87, 79.7, 76, 84.9, 79.2, 81, 82.1, 
81.2, 98, 90.3, 84, 83.1, 87, 79.3, 83, 82.1, 73.3, 93.3, 80, 
79.6, 87, 79, 79.1, 81.3, 82.1, 70.8, 80.3, 80.8, 95.6, 80.7, 
83.7, 84, 79.4, 73.9, 78.6, 84.6, 79.7, 84, 82.9, 80, 82.6, 84, 
81, 70.4, 82.6, 63.1, 72.7, 76.7, 80, 89, 81.5, 82.9, 81.4, 82.14, 
82.5, 80.6, 79.3, 79.8, 77.1, 75.5, 82.4, 77.3, 98, 85, 79, 94.4, 
81.1, 87, 73.1, 76.5, 67.7, 79.2, 77.3, 73.6, 73.4, 82.6, 83, 
75.6, 78, 84, 75.6, 75.6, 84.4, 84.6, 81, 78.7, 84.6, 84.6, 75.6, 
75.6, 75.6, 82), FermentationTempCelsius = c(19L, 18L, 21L, 9L, 
10L, 22L, 10L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 22L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
19L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 9L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 22L, 21L, 19L, 
18L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 12L, 23L, 21L, 10L, 9L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 21L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 10L, 19L, 
19L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 21L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 9L, 22L, 14L, 20L, 
19L, 19L, 20L, 18L, 14L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
21L, 10L, 21L, 21L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 20L, 17L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 
22L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 15L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 10L, 
12L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 21L, 99L, 
19L, 19L, 22L, 16L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 18L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 
17L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 23L, 19L, 20L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L, 18L, 21L, 19L, 21L, 21L, 12L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 12L, 21L, 21L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 21L), Yeast = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Wyeast 1056 - American Ale", "Wyeast 1272 - American Ale II", 
"Wyeast 2007 - Pilsen Lager", "Wyeast 3711 - French Saison"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-196L))
```

Comment: Show the code you used to impute values including any packages that you loaded with the `library()` function. Many implementations of multiple imputation return complete data sets, not just the imputed variables.

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: My *guess* is that you could have imputed directly into the original frame without the problems (and risks) of bringing it back in as you are now. As @dcarlson suggested, if you show the your imputation code then it should be simpler to fix it *there* instead of repairing it *here*.

Comment: @r2evans thank you so much for your reminder. I will take note next time I post my question

Comment: @dcarlson I have updated the code I use, I use MICE for my imputation. Thank you

Comment: @AnNguyen Can you provide some of your data with `dput(head(data))`? You can just edit the original question and provide it there. Or if the data isn't too long, then you can just do `dput(data)`.

Comment: Just use `imi<-mice(data, m=5, maxit=10)` and then use `complete(imi)` to return the five imputed data sets. They will be complete and your imputations will be better because you have used all of the variables to impute the missing values.

Comment: Dear Andrew, I have edited my question. I'm really sorry because I don't know whether it's the correct way to paste the data. @AndrewGillreath-Brown

Comment: @dcarlson thank you so much. I have tried the 2 steps as you suggested. However, I still cannot see the original data frame being updated with the imputed values. Is there any next step I should follow to get the data frame with imputed data? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @dcarlson I have managed to see the updated data frame now. Thank you so so much!

Comment: @AnNguyen I've updated my answer with dcarlson's suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

As @dcarlson recommended, you can run `mice` on the entire dataframe, then you can use `complete` to get the whole output dataframe. Then, you can join the new data with your original dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mice)

imi <- mice(data, m=5, maxit=10)
imi_complete <- complete(imi)

res <- data %>%
  dplyr::left_join(.,  imi_complete %>% dplyr::select(Name, ABV, EBC), by = "Name") %>%
  dplyr::select(-c(ABV.x, EBC.x)) %>%
  dplyr::rename("ABV" = ABV.y, "EBC" = EBC.y)
```

Output

```
 head(res)
                                 Name  IBU     OG  PH AttenuationLevel FermentationTempCelsius                       Yeast ABV EBC
1                                Buzz 60.0 1044.0 4.4             75.0                      19  Wyeast 1056 - American Ale 4.5  20
2                       Trashy Blonde 41.5 1041.7 4.4             76.0                      18  Wyeast 1056 - American Ale 4.1  15
3 Berliner Weisse With Yuzu - B-Sides  8.0 1040.0 3.2             83.0                      21  Wyeast 1056 - American Ale 4.2   8
4                        Pilsen Lager 55.0 1060.0 4.4             80.0                       9  Wyeast 2007 - Pilsen Lager 6.3  30
5                  Avery Brown Dredge 59.0 1069.0 4.4             67.0                      10  Wyeast 2007 - Pilsen Lager 7.2  10
6                      Electric India 38.0 1045.0 4.4             88.9                      22 Wyeast 3711 - French Saison 7.5  15
```

**Old**

Since there's no id column in the new dataframe, you can just `mutate` to replace the columns in the original dataframe with the output from the new dataframe. However, it would be better practice to impute directly into the original dataframe (as suggested by @dcarlson and @r2evans), so that you can ensure that you have the data on the correct rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

df_orig %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(ABV = df_new$ABV, EBC = df_new$EBC)
```

Output

```
  id ABV EBC    third
1  1 -61 -58 37.94029
2  2 -80 -67 47.81479
3  3 -62 -66 48.85903
4  4 -69 -78 23.18026
5  5 -51 -77 29.91952
```

Data

```
df_orig <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
      ABV = c(
        38.9932923251763,
        20.0923723727465,
        37.640398349613,
        31.4673039061017,
        49.192731983494
      ),
      EBC = c(
        42.341671793256,
        32.936319950968,
        33.8184517389163,
        21.5938150603324,
        22.8182014194317
      ),
      third = c(
        37.9402944352478,
        47.8147878032178,
        48.8590325415134,
        23.1802612892352,
        29.9195193173364
      )
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-5L)
  )

df_new <-
  structure(
    list(
      ABV = c(-61,-80,-62,-69,-51),
      EBC = c(-58,-67,-66,-78,-77)
    ),
    class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",
              "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-5L),
    groups = structure(
      list(.rows = structure(
        list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of",
                  "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )),
      row.names = c(NA,-5L),
      class = c("tbl_df",
                "tbl", "data.frame")
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. It works now! you are a life savior! May I ask how can I make these new mutated data into a data frame? My original data frame doesn't change, there is just imputed data in the working console now. Thank you a lot

Comment: Dear Andrew, thank you so much. I have edited the code that I use for the imputation, I hope you can have a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: Dear Andrew, thank you so so much for your answer. I have understood it now!